# ConnectionString for dreamweaver and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I'm trying to create a connection string in dreamweaver with MySQL.
It is my first tutorial with php and MySQL so excuse me if I'm missing something.
This is my connectionString code:

```
  <?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_explorecalifornia= "mysql:host=localhost;
dbname=explorecalifornia;charset=utf8";
$database_explorecalifornia = "explorecalifornia";
$username_explorecalifornia = "root";
$password_explorecalifornia = "";
$explorecalifornia = mysql_pconnect($hostname_explorecalifornia,
$username_explorecalifornia, $password_explorecalifornia) or trigger_error
(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

I'm getting this error :

```
Deprecated: mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will
be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
C:\wamp\www\dwwithphp\Connections\explorecalifornia.php on line 9
```

I tried using mysql_connect(),mysqli() and PDO() but I also have an error:

```
    Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
 failed: No such host is known. in
 C:\wamp\www\dwwithphp\Connections\explorecalifornia.php on line 9
```

similar error for the other methods.
the last two days I've been searching for a solution with no luck.
I'M using :Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12,MySQL 5.6.17 and Dreamweaver cs5

**Edit**
I tried uninstalling wamp server and reinstalling it but it didn't work 
I've got the same errors. I don't know what to do next,  i really need help.

Comment: go through this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) you may find something useful.

Comment: I checked your link but I didn't find something to help me. Thanks @HassanMurtaza

Answer (score 0):

The mysql php APIs deal with constructing the connection string `mysql:host=hostname` stuff internally.

Friends don't help friends connect with the old, nasty, deprecated, insecure `mysql_` api.

To connect with mysqli, you want something like this:

```
$hostname = "localhost";  
$database = "explorecalifornia";
$username = "CONCEALED";
$password = "CONCEALED";

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conn ->connect_error) {
die('Connect Error (' . $conn ->connect_errno . ') '
        . $conn ->connect_error);

$conn->set_charset('utf8') || die "cannot set character set.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;-)

STEP One: The connexion in the DB (connexion.php)

```js
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_connexion = "localhost";
$database_connexion = "apc";
$username_connexion = "root";
$password_connexion = "";
$connexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_connexion, $username_connexion, $password_connexion) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

STEP TWO: In your (exemple.php)

```js
<?php require_once('connexion.php'); ?>

<?php
mysqli_select_db( $connexion, $database_connexion);
$query_ecoles = "SELECT * FROM exempletable1";
$ecoles = mysqli_query($connexion, $query_ecoles) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_ecoles = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ecoles);
$totalRows_ecoles = mysqli_num_rows($ecoles);
?>
```

100 % working,

The idea is to change the mysql by mysqli and the order of the connection variable in the example.php page.....